Allow high cardinality to resource name metric with path
How do I make my spring boot (version 3) application send the resource_name metric to datadog with high cardinality?
It looks like this:

GET /api/v2/fruits/{fruit_name} and the number of requests, p99 and so on

And I want:

GET /api/v2/fruits/orange and the number of requests, p99 and so on
GET /api/v2/fruits/apple and the number of requests, p99 and so on
GET /api/v2/fruits/banana and the number of requests, p99 and so on

My code:
@Configuration
class FruitsRouter {

    @Bean
    fun fruits(handler: FruitsHandler) = coRouter {
        accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).nest {
            "/api/v2/fruits/{fruit_name}".nest {
                POST("", handler::doSomething)
            }
        }
    }
}
``

